# multiplication of specific column in data frame without change in Pattren

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, python-requests

I have two data frames namely shares and Log_Returns. I want to multiply first digit of shares with 1st column of Log_Returns. 2nd digit of shares with 2nd column and so on.

```
shares
           0
0   0.319297
1  99.680703

Log_return

       HIGH       MID
0 -1.998061 -1.991331
1 -0.014573 -1.981635
2 -2.015117 -1.978619
3  0.028488 -2.000455
```

I have tried the following code but got the output in series.

```
for j in range(Log_return.shape[1]):
            i = j
            for k in range(len(Log_return)):
                print(shares.iloc[i, 0] * Log_return.iloc[k, j])


-0.6379746350243671
-0.004652966683445539
-0.6434205307519527
0.009096189190505598
-198.49724749816215
-197.53080296760479
-197.23014837824016
-199.40677745293362

I want someone to help me for finding this results.
Log_return

       HIGH         MID
B -0.637975 -198.497247
C -0.004653 -197.530803
D -0.643421 -197.230148
E  0.009096 -199.406777
```

Answer (score 0):

using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

np.multiply(log_return, shares.T)
```

should give the desired output.